# How find out the lengh of NSData array?

Tags: ios, swift, image, nsdata

I have an array of images to be submitted.

```
var images = [NSData]()
```

I need before I submit these images to check their total size; because of the server limitation.

I've tried following code but it's not giving me the actual size.

```
if (images.description.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF32StringEncoding) >= 3900000)
{
    print("Max of images size reached")
} else {
    // Continue
}
```

Comment: Do you want to find the number of NSData elements in the array, or the size of individual NSData objects?

Comment: @Woodstock I know who to find the number of elements, I just need the total size of all images in Byte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are looking for the total size of all `NSData` elements of the array, you need to compute the aggregate length. One way of doing it is with `reduce`:

```
let totalLength = arr.reduce(0) {$0 + $1.length}
```

This is a short way of writing a loop:

```
var totalLength = 0
for let image in images {
    totalLength += image.length
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
let totalLength = images.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.length }
```